# breakurl doesn't work with xelatex

Tags: xetex, hyperref

I'm trying to use the `breakurl` package with xelatex but can't get even the following minimum working example to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
% dvips added as per breakurl manual
% also fails without it
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Compile with xelatex and you get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \headerps@out 
                         {/burl@stx null def /BU.S { /burl@stx null def } de...
l.311 }
```

Is this package just incompatible or am I missing some special incantation?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `dvips` option to begin with.

Comment: The breakurl manual explicitly recommends it if you get the above error.  But it doesn't compile without it either.

Comment: You don't need `breakurl`, that's all!

Comment: Yes you do...without it (just with hyperref using XeLaTeX0 URIs will not break on the slash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need it. Only the dvips driver has problems to break links and needs breakurl. xdvipdfmx (used by xetex) works without it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\textwidth=2cm
\begin{document}
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218196/breakurl-doesnt-work-with-xelatex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was hoping to use it since I inherited a file with multiple `burlalt` commands where the alt text includes underscores.  Guess I'll have to manually swap the arguments and escape the underscores.

Comment: You could say `\let\burlalt\href`.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to try that.  Escaping the underscores might be tricky but `let` is a good fix for swapping the arguments.  Thanks.