# After selecting XeLaTex as compiler, getting a weird text at the beginning of doc

Tags: xetex, multilingual

After selecting XeLaTex, I am getting this text before tittle of my pdf file

```
burl@stx null def /BU.S /burl@stx null def def /BU.SS currentpoint /burl@lly exch d...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That looks like some PostScript code, but without a demo document to show how it arises, it's hard to help

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218196/47927 ? But I can't tell whether this is really related to your problem, since you don't show any code of your document.