RStudio + LaTeX template: compilation error undefined control sequence -- how to debug this myself?
I am creating a LaTeX template based on the template provided by Springer Nature link .. and direct download link
When rendering I get the following error:
compilation failed- error
Undefined control sequence.
\__hook shipout/firstpage ...geHook \headerps@out 
                                                  {/burl@stx null def /BU.S ...
l.91 \item D
            ata availability

My question is this: how do I debug this? Which systematic process can I use to unravel the source of the error ... I would be happy with a 'how-to-fix-the-error' answer, but really I would prefer to understand how to work it out for myself.
The main issue is backtracing ... where does the hook, shipout etc come from?
...I am not the only one to lament TeX debugging :-)

I have stripped the Springer template down quite a lot (it is loaded with comments and placeholder text), but it still includes all relevant packages etc.:
%\documentclass[sn-vancouver,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Vancouver Reference Style
\documentclass[]{sn-jnl}%

%% Added by S. O'Neill, as required by pandoc
\usepackage{hyperref}%
% \usepackage{iftex}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}%
% \usepackage{lmodern}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage{textcomp}
% \usepackage{upquote}
% \usepackage[]{microtype}
% \usepackage{parskip}
% \usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{fancyvrb}
% \usepackage{framed}
% \usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
% \usepackage{calc}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \usepackage{footnotehyper}
% \usepackage{footnote}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{bookmark}


\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\abstract{The abstract ..}

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

\maketitle

$body$

\backmatter

\bmhead{Supplementary information}

If your article has accompanying supplementary file/s please state so here. 

\bmhead{Acknowledgements}

Acknowledgements are not compulsory. Where included they should be brief. Grant or contribution numbers may be acknowledged.

Please refer to Journal-level guidance for any specific requirements.

\section*{Declarations}

Some journals require declarations to be submitted in a standardised format. Please check the Instructions for Authors of the journal to which you are submitting to see if you need to complete this section. If yes, your manuscript must contain the following sections under the heading `Declarations':

\begin{itemize}
\item Funding
\item Conflict of interest/Competing interests (check journal-specific guidelines for which heading to use)
\item Ethics approval and consent to participate
\item Consent for publication
\item Data availability 
\item Materials availability
\item Code availability 
\item Author contribution
\end{itemize}

\begin{appendices}

\section{Section title of first appendix}\label{secA1}

An appendix contains supplementary information that is not an essential part of the text itself but which may be helpful in providing a more comprehensive understanding of the research problem or it is information that is too cumbersome to be included in the body of the paper.

No bib...

\end{appendices}

% \bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file
%% if required, the content of .bbl file can be included here once bbl is generated
%%\input sn-article.bbl


\end{document}

...as far as I can tell, only hyperref is an additional requirement of Pandoc, which I therefor have added.
The template is used by a minimal-working-example quarto markdown files:
---
title: "This is the title."
date: 2008-02-29
format: 
  pdf:
    template: sn-article-short.tex
echo: false # This is required - the 'Shaded' environment (part of the pandoc template), is not part of the sn template
---

# A headline

Some text


For reference, here is the tail of the latex log file:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2024.3.18)  2 APR 2024 08:35
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.

...

Document Class: sn-jnl 2019/11/18 v0.1: An authoring template for Springer Jour
nal articles
...

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 58.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 58
.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <8.43146> not available
(Font)              size <8> substituted on input line 58.

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <11.04124> on input line 58
.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <5.52061> not available
(Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 58.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/b/it' in size <5.52061> not available
(Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 58.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/b/n' in size <5.52061> not available
(Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 58.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <5.52061> not available
(Font)              size <6> substituted on input line 58.

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <10.03749> on input line 58
.

Package hyperref Warning: Difference (4) between bookmark levels is greater 
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 74.


Package hyperref Warning: Difference (3) between bookmark levels is greater 
(hyperref)                than one, level fixed on input line 78.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook shipout/firstpage ...geHook \headerps@out 
                                                  {/burl@stx null def /BU.S ...
l.91 \item D
            ata availability 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13572 strings out of 477600
 212159 string characters out of 5839383
 509268 words of memory out of 5000000
 33981 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 480326 words of font info for 89 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 360 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 85i,7n,90p,329b,424s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.


Googling the offending bit (\headerps@out ) leads to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218196/breakurl-doesnt-work-with-xelatex . . .  it works, when using lualatex (add pdf-engine: lualatex to the yaml block)

This seems a 'how-to-fix-the-error' answer - thank you very much for a quick solution.

Well you ask how to debug this.
The error is quite at the begin, so at first you check if something in the body is really relevant. This is not the case, so we replace that by some dummy text.
Then we check if any of the packages are relevant by commenting and deleting them in blocks. This lead to this document (amsmath is needed as the slightly buggy class uses amsmath commands without loading the package itself):
\documentclass[]{sn-jnl}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}

Then you look at the error message: An undefined command is used and happily the error gives you directly some indication as it mentions the shipout/firstpage hook. Hooks are mentioned in usrguide.pdf which points you to lthooks-doc.pdf (or you search the internet), and that will tell you that you can use (in the preamble) \ShowHook{shipout/firstpage} to look into this hook.
This gives
-> The hook 'shipout/firstpage':
> Code chunks:
>     hyperref -> \Hy@FirstPageHook 
>     breakurl -> \headerps@out {/burl@stx null
...

and tells you that the breakurl package is the problem.
You can then look into the class and search for breakurl and will find:
\gdef\breakurldefns{%
\if@pdflatex\else%
  \RequirePackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}%
%  \let\href\burlalt%
\fi}%
\breakurldefns%

Then if you have a bit knowledge about the differences in the TeX engine you can perhaps guess that the problem is that you are using xelatex and the breakurl doesn't work with this engine. Or you do what you did now: you ask for help.
Options to solve the error are to use another engine (with lualatex and pdflatex breakurl will either not be loaded or quit silently), or to disable the loading:
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{breakurl}{}
\makeatother
\documentclass[]{sn-jnl}%

I would also report the error, the class could use a better test here.

Wow. That seems like a good 'understand-how-it-works' answer - thank you very much for a quick and detailed response.
I have to say, that debug process is not very intuitive - you obviously know you way around TeX/LaTeX :-)
I understand (and accept) of course, that searching the web is probably the best way to find answers, but knowing what search string will do the trick is not trivial.
..again thanks for helping out!

Regardless if you repair a bicycle or debug some piece of code or klick on some symbols to navigate in some app: you need some skills which you only acquire by experience.
